# Using custom php.ini in a specific folder

Tags: apache, php, cpanel, whm

I've got full control of my Apache / WHM / CPanel server.  I have a default PHP.ini file set up for everything and that is just fun for the production server.

On the same server, I have a staging/testing server - and on it I want display_errors to be ON instead of OFF (as it is in the production site of course).  How can I tell the server to use a local PHP.ini file in that directory?

Thanks!

Comment: Refer to http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add an htaccess file to the dir with the rule php_flag  display_errors on

Answer (score 4):

In complement to @i_forget answer: You can use the [php_admin_value & php_value & php_flag & php_admin_flag](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) directives to alter specific settings on a Virtualhost or on a directory.

```
<Directory /path/to/foo>
    php_value       include_path   ".:/var/www/foo/lib:/usr/share/php5/apc"
    php_admin_flag  file_uploads   on
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/my/tmp/upload/"
</Directory>
```

php_admin_value is safer than php_value (idem for flag) as the application cannot use ini_set to alter the value.

Here's it's one a `Directory` tag, so it could be as well on a .htaccess but you should'nt use .htaccess files if you have access to the configuration, use `AllowOverride None` :-). It could be as well on the VirtualHost, so before the the Directory tag.

Comment: Thanks, but for now I think it's simpler to do the above one... eventually I'll investigate doing it the right way as you described.

Comment: amazing worked good.. i turned file uploads only for phpmyadmin good.